# How do I use CountVectorizer to get the count of a phrase without counting words in the phrase?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tokenize

I am working on an NLP project and I hope to tokenize sentences and get counts of different tokens. Sometimes I hope a few words to be a phrase and do not count the words inside the phrase.

I have found CountVectorizer in scikit-learn useful in counting phrases, but I could not figure out how to remove the words inside the phrases.

For example:

```py
words = ['cat', 'dog', 'walking', 'my dog']
example = ['I was walking my dog and cat in the park']
vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=words, ngram_range=(1,2))
dtm = vect.fit_transform(example)
print(dtm)
```

I got:

```
>>> vect.get_feature_names()
['cat', 'dog', 'walking', 'my dog']
>>> print(dtm)
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (0, 2)    1
  (0, 3)    1
```

What I want is:

```
>>> print(dtm)
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 2)    1
  (0, 3)    1
```

But I want to keep `'dog'` in the dictionary because it may appear on its own in other text.

Comment: The question is not clear. You want to remove the words which appear inside other phrases? Then what does "`But I want to keep 'dog' in the dictionary because it may appear on its own in other text.`" mean?

Comment: Exactly. I was saying that in this sentence, I want to keep 'my dog' but remove 'dog', but in case there is no 'my dog' in the sentence, I want keep 'dog'.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any specific config in `CountVectorizer` to apply the longer string first and remove it from the string to prevent counting the shorter substring.

Hence, one solution can be using `CountVectorzier` as what you did. Aftwerwards, 
iterate over the words to find the words that are contained in the longer phrases, and then minus the number of longer phrases from the shorter phrases that are contained, in the first result of `CountVectorizer`.

Comment: @YuanChen I don't know.